# my ajax file is not working in internet explore8.what should i do now?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My select DROP DOWN box is not working properly in IE8.I have two select box in HTML,the data are stored in database(mysql).The second select box value is shown after choose my first select box value.This function is working properly in chrome and Firefox.Please help me.
    function getCity(stateId,divId){
    $.post("state.php", { state: stateId, format:"html"},
        function(data)
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML=data;
        });
    }

Comment: What is not working? What did you do to solve the problem? That question doesn't show a very high amount of time you put into solving it..

Comment: Define "not working". Also, how does your select look like and what is it surrounded with?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's not works in **IE8**.

If you need to support **IE8**, take `JSONP` or `postMessage`, or combination of both.

Comment: Why would plain AJAX not work in IE8? IE8 supports `XMLHttpRequest`? jQuery 1.x even has a fallback for IE6 & 7.

Comment: JSONP is only useful for IE5 or so (and even then just maybe) or for cross-domain requests (where CORS should be used instead), and`postMessage` serves a different purpose altogether.